# C++ Broken code (switch quantity not an integer)

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement

I have no clue why this is not working and this is my first time working with the `switch` statement.

```
int main() {
    string typed;
    ofstream theFile("players.txt");
    ifstream theFile2("players.txt");
    cout << "Do you want to read or write" << endl;
    cin >>typed;
    switch(typed){
    case "write":
        cout << "Enter players Id, Name and Money" << endl;
        cout << "Press Ctrl+Z to exit\n" << endl;
        while(cin >> idNumber >> name >> money){
            theFile << idNumber << ' ' << name << ' ' << money << endl;
        }break;
    case "read":
        while (theFile2 >> id >> nametwo >> moneytwo){
            cout << id << ", " << nametwo << ", " << moneytwo << endl;
        }break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is a string an integer?

Comment: you can't switch based on a string.

Comment: ya just looked back and else did not work and no its a string.

Comment: so then i will just have to interlace if statements?

Comment: Or change the write/read to depend on 0/1 or something like that.

Comment: i took some code out it did not have any thing to do with this part and its asking the user if they want to read the file or write in it so that would not work i don't think.

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you — "switch quantity is not an integer" is saying 'the value in `switch (typed)` is not an integer'.  You will need to learn how to interpret error messages, but that is fairly straight-forward as error messages go.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with just normal equality-testing:

```
if( typed == "write" ) {
   // ...
} else if( typed == "read" ) {
   // ...
} else {
   cout << "Whoops, try again" << endl;
}
```

The advantages of `switch` are not relevant in this case, and you can't switch on string values.  It can only be used for primitive data-types.

There are other solutions that use `switch`, but these involve mapping string values to integer constants, and this would be overkill for your application.  So, while I'll mention it's possible, I'll provide no details to avoid the temptation to bloat your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think these people just don't have any imagination! If there isn't a switch for strings, let's create one! Below is an example which isn't quite as nice as I'd like it to be.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

void sswitch (std::string const&)
{
}

template <typename F, typename... T>
void sswitch (std::string const& value, F&& arg, T&&... args)
{
    if (value == arg.first) {
        arg.second();
    }
    else {
        sswitch(value, std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
}

template <typename F>
std::pair<std::string, F> scase(std::string const& s, F&& f)
{
    return std::make_pair(s, std::forward<F>(f));
}

int main()
{
    std::ofstream theFile("players.txt");
    std::ifstream theFile2("players.txt");
    std::string input;
    if (std::cin >> input) {
        sswitch(input,
                scase("write", [&]{
                        std::cout << "Enter players Id, Name and Money\n";
                        std::cout << "Press Ctrl+Z to exit\n\n";
                        int idNumber, name, money;
                        while(std::cin >> idNumber >> name >> money) {
                            theFile << idNumber << ' ' << name << ' ' << money << '\n';
                        }
                    }),
                scase("read", [&]{
                        int id, nametwo, moneytwo;
                        while (theFile2 >> id >> nametwo >> moneytwo){
                            std::cout << id << ", " << nametwo << ", " << moneytwo << '\n';
                        }
                    })
                );
            }
}
```